# Swift remove optional from Dictionary of Dictionary

Tags: json, xcode, swift, api

I'm taking data from an api in the form of JSON. I get a variable of dynamicType `Swift.Dictionary<NSObject, Swift.AnyObject>` and call this variable `myDictionary`. When I ask for `print(myDictionary["keyA"])` it returns the value (inner dictionary) associated with "keyA", but it returns it as a `Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>`.

How do I set a variable with the inner dictionary that isn't optional? Or how to I access the inner dictionary values?

Comment: You can't. Anything in a dictionary is by default optional, as it is always possible that when you request value for a key, the key is not there, and therefore the value will be nil. If you want the result to not be optional, you can unwrap it.

Comment: What type has the inner dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

All dictionary accesses are returned as *optionals* because the key used might not exist in the dictionary, and thus `nil` is returned in that case.  You can use optional casting `as?` along with optional binding `if let` to make sure the value exists, that it is a dictionary as expected, and unwrap it:

```
if let innerDictionary = myDictionary["keyA"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject] {
    // if we get here, "keyA" is a valid key in myDictionary and
    // we got the type right.  innerDictionary is now unwrapped and ready
    // to use.
}
```

I used `[NSObject: AnyObject]` as the innerDictionary type.  If you know more about it, you can use a more specific cast, for example `as? [String: String]` if you know that both keys and values are of type `String`.  If you are wrong, the optional cast will return `nil` and the block will not be entered because the optional binding will not succeed.